# Obtener registros que no sumen más de un límite

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE Actividades (Num INT PRIMARY KEY, Actividad VARCHAR(100), Horas INT);
```

Ejemplos de los registros:

```
INSERT INTO Actividades VALUES (1, "Barrer salones Edificio", 2);
INSERT INTO Actividades VALUES (2, "Trapear salones", 5);
INSERT INTO Actividades VALUES (3, "Lavar baños", 3);
INSERT INTO Actividades VALUES (4, "Sacar basura", 1);
```

Quiero hacer una consulta de las actividades cuyas horas sean menores a 8 horas, pero tienen que cumplir exactamente menos de 8 horas.

Como, por ejemplo, el número 2 y el 3 hacen un total de 8 horas
o el 1, 2 y 4 un total de 8 horas.

Que formen grupos de 8 horas totales.

Agregue esta consulta pero solo me da 8 registros con diferentes horas y no con 8 horas en total

```
SELECT Horas 
FROM Actividades 
WHERE Horas<=8 LIMIT 8;
```

También intenté:

```
SELECT actividad, SUM(horas) as Total
FROM actividades
WHERE horas>0 and horas<=8
GROUP BY actividad;
```

De esta forma puede quedar

[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: Sería así: `SELECT Horas FROM Actividades WHERE Horas < 8;`

Comment: pero en grupos de 8 horas, como sería?

Comment: ¿Debe funcionar en PostgreSQL y MySQL? ¿Solo en una de ellas? ¿Podrías ser más específico? ¿Debe mostrar un único grupo que contenga registros que sumen menos de 8? En caso negativo, ¿cómo deben agruparse en el resultado? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo debería responder la consulta a los datos que has proporcionado?

Comment: en MySQL estaría bien.
Los datos son aleatorios pero deben de sumar 8, como lo di en en el ejemplo el numero 2 y el 3 hacen un total de 8 horas o el 1, 2 y 4 un total de 8 horas.

@OscarGarcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lo que deseas necesitas apoyarte en, al menos, una variable de sesión que lleve la cuenta del número de horas que pasan el filtro, impidiendo agregar un registro cuya suma supere el umbral deseado (en este ejemplo, el contenido de la variable de sesión `@limite`):

```
SET @total = 0;
SET @limite = 8;

SELECT
  *, @total := @total + Horas acumulado
FROM
  Actividades
WHERE
  @total + Horas <= @limite;
```

Obtendrás este resultado:

| Num | Actividad | Horas | acumulado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Barrer salones Edificio | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Trapear salones | 5 | 7 |
| 4 | Sacar basura | 1 | 8 |

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea en la siguiente URL:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sGaPz9Ask7raMVKbRMqWX4/0

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!